# Scrollview or Listview (With respect to performance for thousands of rows)

Tags: listview, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I've a screen in my app that will contain thousands of rows, (like twitter's dashboard), where a user will keep scrolling, do somme stuff, read some stuff and again..keep scrolling. Obviously, i'll implement the "load more" feature so that there is a proper distribution.
One of the things to keep in mind would be to somewhat cache the json response so that the list appears smooth. 
Right now, i've CursorAdapter as a sort of recommended approaches in mind. 
However, i've heard its quite difficult to implement(i've never used or written code about it before).
Also, i've observed that scrollview loads all the data at once (unlike getView() method's per screen scroll). Hence scrolling is smoother if i create a list using for loop in scrollview. But is it recommended?

Each row will be clickable. Also, there will be child views inside some rows that will have some specific actions. I'm fine with listview except one problem. Currently my json data has an indepth tree like object structure. Hence, the adapter is kind of heavy loaded, and this in turn has affected the performance of my listview. Also, when i scroll up and down continuously, the rows lose their hierarchy and start showing inconsistent data. (not all types of rows, but asically only the ones that contain too many conditions before they show me the content in the row)

Comment: You can create a custom layout (Recommend a tablerow layout) for each row, and then dynamically populate a scrollview or listview with these rows programmatically. If each row is clickable, I would recommend that you use the listView, otherwise a scrollView

Comment: @SamratDutta please check the second paragraph that i've added. That is a bit more of description to my requirement.